# How to connect Expo Go physical device from another network to my laptop's tunneled app?

Tags: react-native, go, expo

I can successfully connect my Expo Go app to my local server using the same network when starting it with

```
npx expo start
```

However, I also need to be able to test it using another physical device using a different OS that is connected to another network. To achieve it I was testing tunnel connections with my own physical phone using its own internet data so it uses another network.

```
npx expo start --tunnel
```

ngrok is a dependency with version 4.1.1 which is required for tunneling. However, when I start the server and try to connect to it, I get this error.

```
java.net.UnkownHostException: Unable to resolve host "_nq4...m.myUsername.8081.exp.direct": No address associated with hostname
```

I've searched for a whole day with no answer on this. I am not using any emulators. I do not know how to solve this error. Why can the hostname not be resolved? Everything seems to be okay, but I cannot connect to my running tunneled server even if I am on the same network. So, I assume something's not right with my tunnel setup maybe?

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone, I had tried so many fixes for my project and couldn't find a solution.

I just opened up a new project and didn't change anything in its package.json (I previously added extra commands and edited npm-start command too). Everything vanilla, just install ngrok globally. Now my

`npx expo start --tunnel`

is working with different networks.